# mamp error_logging and display_error are both not working

Tags: php, mamp

So really stuck at this point. My local environment which is using mamp will not display any errors at all. 
I have established which php.ini it is loading so i am seeing the changes i am making changing in the phpinfo. But the log will no longer get generated and when i put dispaly_errors on as well nothing happens. Just blank screen.

settings below: (using mamp basic NOT pro)

```
error_reporting  =  E_ALL
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
log_errors = On
error_log = "/Applications/MAMP/logs/php_error.log"
```

any help is appreciated. Driving me nuts :)

Thanks
/s

Answer (score 0):

You can display errors by adding these lines directly in your PHP code:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

For more details about errors handling you can read this post on my blog: [Handle PHP errors and exceptions](http://en.open-lamp.com/handle-php-errors-and-exceptions/)